# How to clear kerberos config

Tags: authentication, kerberos, kinit

I am setting my machine as a kerberos client. I have a question on how the kerberos config file actually take effect and how to clear its effect. My experiment is as follow.

Step 1, without editing the `/etc/krb5.conf` file, I typed `kinit` and got what I expected.

```
aaaa@bbbb:~> kinit
kinit(v5): Configuration file does not specify default realm when parsing name aaaa
```

Step 2, I edited `/etc/krb5.conf` to put in valid kerberos server information, and typed `kinit` again.

```
aaaa@bbbb:~> kinit 
Password for aaaa@bbbb:
pingluo@zhejiangNEW:~> klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000
Default principal: aaaa@bbbb

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
08/13/14 11:36:34  08/13/14 21:36:34  krbtgt/bbbb@bbbb
    renew until 08/20/14 11:36:34
```

So I could get a valid kerberos ticket, which shows my configuration is correct.

Step 3, Destroy the credential with `kdestroy`.

Step 4, I deleted `/etc/krb5.conf` with the hope that this would clear kerberos config and `kinit` would show the message in step 1. But, I was surprised to see the message in step 2. So the kerberos config, while it had been deleted, was still in effect! I restarted my machine and it was still the same.

Can anybody explain what has happened and how can I get rid of kerberos completely? My machine runs OpenSUSE 13.1. The krb5 client is 1.11.3.

Answer (score 2):

Kinit can also use DNS lookups to find the KDC for your realm. It looks for these 
records.

> _kerberos._udp.EXAMPLE.COM.         IN  SRV  10  0   88  kdc1.example.com.
>   _kerberos._udp.EXAMPLE.COM.         IN  SRV  20  0   88  kdc2.example.com.
>   _kerberos-master._udp.EXAMPLE.COM.  IN  SRV   0  0   88  kdc1.example.com.
>   _kerberos-adm._tcp.EXAMPLE.COM.     IN  SRV   0  0  749  kdc1.example.com.
>   _kpasswd._udp.EXAMPLE.COM.          IN  SRV   0  0  464  kdc1.example.com.

You can turn this off by specifying options in the krb5.conf file. If that isn't the problem I suggest running strace on kinit to find out where it is getting the information
from.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible it looked at your current cached credentials.  Type kdestroy, then kinit and see if that clears it.

Comment: I should mention in my post that I did `kdestroy` before I typed `kinit`. It was the same. I Updated post. Thanks.